# How to scroll to a div of one component from another component in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, routes, angular6

I have 3 components Home , Add , Status .

In Home I have a section id "about"

In Navbar I have Home , About , Add , Status .

When in "Home" and I click on "About" in navbar it scrolls to About Section .
When in About / Add and click on "About" in navbar it loads the Home Component but does not scroll to Home although the URL changes to http://localhost:4200/#about .

Can you please provide a solution for this or redirect to a exiting solution as I am not able to find it .

This is how my navbar looks :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="../../../assets/img/logo.png" width="70" height="50" alt=""></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" (click)="toggleNavbar()"
          data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="true"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" [ngClass]="{ 'show': navbarOpen }" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li (click)="toggleNavbar()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
          class="nav-item ">
        <a [routerLink]="['/']" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li (click)="toggleNavbar()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
          class="nav-item ">
        <a [routerLink]="['/add']" class="nav-link">Add Event</a>
      </li>
      <li (click)="toggleNavbar()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
          class="nav-item ">
        <a [routerLink]="['/status']" class="nav-link">Status</a>
      </li>
       <li (click)="toggleNavbar()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
          class="nav-item ">
        <a [routerLink]="['/']"  [fragment]="'about'" class="nav-link">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [ng2-scroll-to-el](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-scroll-to-el).

Install through npm:

`npm install --save ng2-scroll-to-el`

Then include in your apps module:

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ScrollToModule } from 'ng2-scroll-to-el';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ScrollToModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Usage:

In your .html:

```
<div class="home" #home></div>
<button class="btn" (click)="scrollToHome(home)">Top</button>
```

In your .ts:

```
import { ScrollToService } from 'ng2-scroll-to-el';

export class DemoComponent {

    constructor(private scrollService: ScrollToService) {}

    scrollToHome(element) {
        this.scrollService.scrollTo(element, 700, 0);
    }
}
```

Working [demo](https://marcinmichalik.github.io/ng-scrollTo/).